# Calling dynamically created element with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a dynamically created element via $(this), is it possible?

Eg:

```
$(".el").on("click",function(){
  $("body").append("<div class='new'></div>");
    // call class .new via $(this)
});
```

**Is it possible to call class .new from $(".el")
Or calling $(".el") from $(".new") from another function**

Answer (score 3):

Reasigning `this` is imposible without calling an other function. It would anyway be better to cache your element, saving it in a var. You can use this code :

```
$(".el").on("click",function(){
    var $el = $("<div class='new'></div>").appendTo('body');
    // $el will be $('.new') and you can call jQuery function like that
    // $el.addClass('work');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign `this` at that point, but you could just assign the new element to a variable when you create it. That way you can simply use the new variable instead of the keyword this.

```
$(".el").on("click",function(){
  var newEl = $('<div class="new"></div>');
  $("body").append(newEl);
});
```

You can on the other hand use the new element as `this` in another function. To do this you use the `call` or `apply` functions.

```
someFunc.call(newEl); // Makes newEl become this inside the function

var someFunc = function(){
  // this is now newEl within this scope
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.el').on('click',function(){
  var mynewdiv = $('<div class="new"></div>');
  $('body').append(mynewdiv);
  //mynewdiv is your dynamically created element.
});
```

or

```
$('.el').on('click',function(){
   var UniqueId = '_id'+ new Date().valueOf();
   $('body').append('<div class="new" data-id="'+UniqueId+'"></div>');
   // $('[data-id='+UniqueId+']') is your created element.
});
```